Ex-convict or cop tries to stop religion based cult
I have been watching this old MGM movie (probably set in 1980's or 90's). It's about this cop/detective (or an ex-convict who was hired as a cop/detective) who tries to stop religion based cult. It's a black cult and I think it's the voodoo type. Anyway I remember that the movie ends with this guy killing the leader but then while driving away for a better life with his new gal, the bad guys shoot and kill her.
Anyone know which movie this is?

The plot sounds like a mash-up of two James Bond movies: Live and Let Die and On Her Majesty's Secret Service

No it's not James Bond. I am 100% sure of this as I am a big fan of James Bond.

Could it be Cobra http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090859/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1 or the Dan Akroyd - Tom Hanks Dragnet http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092925/?ref_=nm_flmg_wr_18?

wait, how do you know it's MGM but not know the title? If you're sure about it being MGM check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Metro-Goldwyn-Mayer_films#1980s

Was there a big snake towards the end of the movie, and the cult tried to sacrifice the girl, but a cop falls in the pit and kills the snake. It was inside some sort of park or zoo.

Was the cop Martin Sheen? You might have seen The Believers, a movie from 1987 where he plays a police psychiatrist who moves to New York with his son after his wife dies in a freak accident.
Starred Martin Sheen and Helen Shaver. Wasn't a good movie but wasn't terrible, drifted a little towards the end. I am waiting for the next post-zombie wave of horror and maybe the whole devil-worshipper thing might come back, with "American Horror Story: Coven" leading the way.

The end doesn't fit too well to his descriptions, though. But was my first thought, too.

It sounds like Night Trap, aka Mardi Gras for the Devil, with Michael Ironside, from 1993.
Some points match with your memories and others are different.
For example the movie ends with the cop and his ex-wife actually driving away for a better life with no further murder. It was before being killed by the cop, that the bad guy tried to kill his new girlfriend.
Plot summary from IMDb:

A man sells his soul to the devil and shows up on a killing spree at Mardi Gras in New Orleans. Leaving a trail of bodies, the apparently indestructible demon challenges the detective to stop him by the end of Mardis Gras or lose his soul. With help from a voodoo lady and his police captain, who remembers the demon from a past Mardis Gras, he gets closer, but risks the destruction of his ex-wife and newly found girlfriend

And well... this is not a MGM movie.
